# image post to aws s3 turns into no type

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am building an express app and am trying to upload a image to s3 using post method,
here is my aws config:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3-v2");

const s3 = new aws.S3();

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: "ca-central-1",
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Invalid file type, only JPEG and PNG is allowed!"), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    acl: "public-read",
    s3,
    bucket: "yelpcampimage",
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: "TESTING_METADATA" });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = upload;
```

and part of my js code:

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(catchAsync(campgrounds.index))
  .post(
    isLoggedIn,
    upload2.single("image"),
    validateCampground,
    catchAsync(campgrounds.createCampground)
  );
```

when I console.log(req.file), the file type is 'image/png',

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'c1.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  size: 15876,
  bucket: 'yelpcampimage',
  key: '1671537988619',
  acl: 'public-read',
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  contentDisposition: null,
  storageClass: 'STANDARD',
  serverSideEncryption: null,
  metadata: { fieldName: 'TESTING_METADATA' },
  location: 'https://yelpcampimage.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/1671537988619',
  etag: '"af821b58730de95a15c28b9a5dee3422"',
  versionId: undefined
}
```

but when I view the image in aws s3, it turns into typeof empty, and the generated object URL is unusable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxDoH.png)

this is what it looks like when I add image directly using s3, the object URL gives back the full image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNTt3.png)

which step did I do wrong? Thanks for the help in advance!

I wasn't able to find any problem like this on Google. I expected the object URL to work and use it in the src arrtibute in my html file to display the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used AWS but from what I understood is that you need to set the content type. This what I found from the package you are using [ContentType](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3-v2#setting-custom-content-type)

And In your code this should be added

```
const upload = multer({
      fileFilter,
      storage: multerS3({
      acl: "public-read",
      s3,
      bucket: "yelpcampimage",
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE, //added line
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: "TESTING_METADATA" });
     },
   key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    },
  }),
});
```

Hope this fixes your issue

Comment: thanks for answering. It turns out that all I need is to add a file extension at the end of URL. In my case that is location+'.png'.